# Xaml parser exception, Quote Expected, Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I've been banging my head over this for some time and couldn't find the cause of the error, please help :/

```
public static ControlTemplate LookUpEditNameCreate(String Name)
    {
        string xaml = @"<ControlTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"" xmlns:dxg=""http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"">
                                            <dxg:GridControl Name=""PART_GridControl"">
                                                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName=" + Name + @"/>
                                                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                                    <dxg:TableView AutoWidth=""True""/>
                                                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                            </dxg:GridControl>
                                        </ControlTemplate>";
        return (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try to change this line:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName=" + Name + @"/>
```

to

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName=""" + Name + @"""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem. Could not solve but found an alternative which was sort of better than this.

```
 XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(licensexml));
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                  //Do the work
                }
```

licensexml variable contains the xml string.

Comment: The question was not about parsing arbitrary xml, it was about instantiating a ControlTemplate programmatically from XAML.